flutter intent fails when debugging
I'm having trouble debugging an intent filter on android.
Technically this is a Flutter app but I don't think that matters as the intent filters are implemented in android and the flutter app is just launched when the intent is triggered.
In release mode the app (running on an android device) correctly gets the intent filter. When I try to debug the app (on the same device after uninstalling the release version of the app) the intent filter fails and instead the website for the intent filters domain opens.
My debug manifest is minimal
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>

And here is the intent filter from the main/AndroidManifest.xml
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="ivanhoehandyman.com.au" android:pathPrefix="/xero/auth_complete" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>


Did you using the same host when you are in debug mode ?
Try the following.. \

set false or remove the android:autoVerify
Update the <data android:scheme="http" /> to   <data android:scheme="http" android:host="ivanhoehandyman.com.au" android:pathPrefix="/xero/auth_complete" />

